# Android Socket not being instantiated

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have been working on an Android project that will connect to a C# server on another computer. I have tested the server side with a C# client but I need an Android client to connect from an android tablet.

The problem I have found is that the socket is not being instantiated and I cannot figure out why. Any guidance would be appreciated, I am new to Android and want to learn.

First off my permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Next in my .java class, a thread is called on a touch event:

```
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
```

And finally we have the thread:

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        {
            try
            {
                Log.i("Project", SERVER_IP);
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                Log.i("Project", serverAddr.toString());

                Log.i("Project", String.valueOf(SERVERPORT));                   
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                Log.i("Project", "Socket created");

                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

                Log.i("Project", "Open paint writer");
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

                Log.i("Project", "Sending Data to PC");
                output.println("Hello from Android");

                Log.i("Project", "out.flush");
                out.flush();

                Log.i("Project", "out.close");
                out.close();

                Log.i("Project", "Data sent to PC, close socket");
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i("IS4432", "Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // display error
            Log.i("Project", "No Internet");
        }
```

I use the Log's to find where the code stops working, it stops on `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);`. It also doesn't catch any exception.

**EDIT - Solved Solution**

I switched from a thread to an `AsyncTask` as advised. I instantiated the socket and then connected it. Now my application is able to send a string to the server

First calling the method from a touch event:

```
getSocket task = new getSocket();
task.execute(new String[] { "PlaceHolder" });
```

And the method, I took notes from a tutorial on [www.vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html):

```
private class getSocket extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String response = "";
        String msg = "Hello, from Android<EOF>";
        socket = new Socket();
        Log.i("Project","Socket instantiated");

        try
        {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT), 5000);
            Log.i("Project","Connection Made");

            // This buffer to receive data from your server  
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            response = in.toString();
            Log.i("Project","Input Stream");

            // This one to send
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            Log.i("Project","Output Stream");

            out.write(msg.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
            out.flush();
            Log.i("Project", msg.getBytes().toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Project","IOException");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Project","Something went Wrong");
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post LogCat error

Comment: There must be. Look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is that if you're just beggining with Android, implement that socket within an `AsyncTask`. It's basically a `Thread` with some improvements you'd need to control by yourself if you used the `Thread` class. Once you're clear about that, you may want start experiencing with `Thread`s themselves, in my opinion starting learning with an `Thread` is a bit 'hardcore'.

Start that socket in your `doInBackground()` method, using something like this:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);

// This buffer to receive data from your server  
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
// This one to send
out = socket.getOutputStream();
```

To read lines from the server:

```
while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
  // In my case, buffer is a String
  ...
}
```

To send out something to the server:

```
// The charset is because my server is in spanish :-)
out.write(msg.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed my code from threaded to using an AsyncTask. I"m not exactly sure what fixed it but changing to AsyncTask and modifying server side solved it.